# Why do games in Windows have better FPS than in Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, steam

When I had Windows 7 on my Samsung R870 (Intel i3 and nvidia GeForce GT 330M), games like Team Fortress 2 (via Steam) ran really smoothly, but when I downloaded and installed Ubuntu and Ubuntu studio, the game runs fairly smoothly for about 15 minutes then my laptop completely turns off.

Why is this the case?

I have also installed the correct graphics driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not necessarily.

They spec-ed out frame rates on a more minimal linux (Ubuntu without Unity to take weight off the video card) and Left4Dead2 had BETTER frame rates on linux.  It's my understanding TF2 runs on the same engine, so in theory if you were running something like XFCE instead of Unity it would have better frame rates on the same hardware.

Look at the threads here that talk about about getting more performance out of wine games (which should run slower because of an extra abstraction layer).  If you tune your box, you will get better frame rates on Linux native games than Windows native games as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is constantly having their drivers tweaked by graphics card companies.
They specifically modify drivers to detect when a game is being run, and optimize from there for performance, crash issues, and other kinds of prioritization.

Linux drivers for AMD/INTEL/NVIDIA are very low level, and obviously you need to expect a high degree of instability. I'm assuming because of the massive amount of operating system flavors.

It'd be nice if they had a higher degree of open source support.

Best of Luck!
-drXploit

Comment: IMHO, Nvidia drivers for linux tend to be the most cared after, and although not as good as they are for Windows, are insanely better than *cough* @AMD 's drivers for Linux, and Intel's aren't bad either.